# Where to assign RenderTransform on animated image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a image in my View, which I want to rotate my image 45 degress when a special event happens. But I keep getting this error all the time:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path
>   'RenderTransform.Angle'

What type of property path do I need to set to accomplish this?

```
var dbAscending = new DoubleAnimation(0, 45, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));
var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(dbAscending);
Storyboard.SetTarget(dbAscending, uc.Cross);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbAscending, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"));
storyboard.Begin();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to assign a `RotateTransform` to your Image's RenderTransform to make your Storyboard work, e.g. like this:

```
<Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ...>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="imageRotation"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Although you could animate this with your Storyboard, it might be easier to just start the animation directly on the RotateTransform object:

```
var rotationAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(45, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
imageRotation.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotationAnimation);
```

Answer (score 2):

A RenderTransform has no Angle property. Make sure there is a RotationTransformation assigned to the RenderTranformation property of the element you are rotating.

```
new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

If you added the Rotation to a TransformGroup the PropertyPath would be (assuming the Rotation is the first child of the group):

```
new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

Comment: Although `RenderTransform.Angle` is a valid property path, as long as the RenderTransform really contains a RotateTransform.

Comment: @Clemens - yes, I added the PropertyPath for that case to show that the property path in the question is more complex than you might expect. It is correct though and will work if the control has the RenderTransform set.

Comment: I think you mean `TransformGroup` by *TransformationGroup*.